# Help Inserting Hyperlinks Into CSS sprite code..Java? HTML?

Tags: hyperlink, sprite, css-sprites, flash-cs5, clickable

It is very simple to do rollover images in CS5 using the built in Javascript, however, I need to do this CSS based.

I've managed to get the code working and the sprites are all wonderful but I seem to have a problem...I need to make these clickable (pointing) to a URL. Ive tried every method including a `<a href>` url in the div line. I tried even placing the url with an image. I do not want to have to start all over using the `<li>` method as Ive seen everywhere else. I cannot even get that to work...so in short is there anyway (simple) way to make the sprite point to a url...thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 


<body> 


<style type="text/css"> 



.sprites { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/facebooksprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 

 } 

 #facebooksprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 

   background-position  : -0px -75px; 
   padding-left:10px;
   float: left;
 } 

 #facebooksprite:hover { 
    background-position  : -0px 0px; 

 } 

.sprites2 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/twittersprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #twittersprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;
 } 

 #twittersprite:hover { 
    background-position  : -0px 0px; 
 } 

 .sprites3 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/flickrsprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #flickrsprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #flickrsprite:hover { 
    background-position  : -0px 0px; 
 } 

  .sprites4 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/youtubesprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #youtubesprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #youtubesprite:hover { 
    background-position  : -0px 0px; 
 } 
 .sprites5 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/tumblrsprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #tumblrsprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #tumblrsprite:hover { 
    background-position  : -0px 0px; 
 } 
 .sprites6 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/bloggersprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #bloggersprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 100px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #bloggersprite:hover { 
   background-position  : -0px 0px;

 } 

.sprites7 { 
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/googleplacessprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #googleplacessprite { 
    height               : 73px; 
    width                : 94px; 
    background-position  : -0px -73px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #googleplacessprite:hover { 
   background-position  : -0px 0px;

 } 

 .sprites8 {
    background-image     : url(http://sheldontechnology.com/social/yelpsprite.png); 
    background-color     : transparent; 
    background-repeat    : no-repeat; 
 } 

 #yelpsprite { 
    height               : 75px; 
    width                : 97px; 
    background-position  : -0px -75px; 
    float:left;

 } 

 #yelpsprite:hover { 
   background-position  : -0px 0px;





</style> 

<div class="sprites" id="facebooksprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites2" id="twittersprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites3" id="flickrsprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites4" id="youtubesprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites5" id="tumblrsprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites6" id="bloggersprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites7" id="googleplacessprite"></div> 
<div class="sprites8" id="yelpsprite"></div> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: To embed your code in, paste it into the editor, highlight it and hit the "{}" button (or indent it all by 4 spaces).  Just for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `div` elements use links - `a` with appropriate `href` attribute pointing to your destinations.

Comment: I hate to ask could you give me an idea what that would take in a code to replace the <div class="sprites" id="facebooksprite"></div> with an a href?. Would I have to start all over?

Comment: in your markup replace <div class="sprites" id="facebooksprite"></div> with <a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="sprites" id="facebooksprite"></a>

Comment: Wow, I am so sorry I been working on this for 6 hours! You solved it in a minute! Thanks you SO kindly for your time and your help, I am very thankful!